# Unable to Convert PFFile to UIImage

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uiimage, pfobject, pffile

I am wondering if I have done anything wrong here.

I have a subclass of `PFUser` which has a property of `profileImage`, which is a `PFFile`

There are some cases when I don't save the `profileImage` right away to Parse and I only pin it to the `localDatastore`.

But when I tried to retrieve it back from the `localDataStore` and use the `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`. It does not return any error, but the NSData returned by the callback **is always nil**.

```
if let profileImage = PGUser.currentUser()?.profileImage {
    profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if  data != nil {
                println("IMAGE DATA FOUND")
                let image = UIImage(data: data!);
                self.profileImageView.image = image;
            }
            else {
                //DATA IS ALWAYS NIL    
                println("NO IMAGE DATA FOUND")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

1. The `PGUser.currentUser()?.profileImage` is **NOT NIL**
2. **No error returned** by the `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` function.
3. BUT the **data** is always
   **NIL**.

Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!!

Comment: What does `error` tell you?

Comment: The problem is that the data is always nil. The data in getDataInBackgroundWithBlock. What could have caused this?

Comment: I don't know, perhaps the `error` parameter will shed some light on the situation

Comment: Error is nil. But data is also nil

Comment: log the file URL, see if you can access it in a browser. were there any errors when it was uploaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80889/discussion-between-wain-and-jayvdiyk).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I solved my problem with this

```
 let profileImage = userPhoto["imageFile"] as PFFile
userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
(imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
if !error {
    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
self.profileImageView.image = image
 }
}
```

Comment: this code wont compile since the parameter of is '(NSData?, NSError?) ' and after I changed to that, the data is still nil